# Flow - type a variable with global type property type

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

I have a global type in `flow-typed` directory like this:

```
import type { UI, User, Projects, Profile } from 'data/redux/redux.flow';

declare type State = {
  +ui: UI,
  +user: User,
  +projects: Projects,
  +profile: Profile,
}
```

each property has its own type imported from `data/redux/redux.flow.js` file.

I wonder is it possible now to do something like below somewhere in my app:

```
type Props = {
  profile: State.profile, //or maybe State$Profile e.t.c
}
```

so basically I dont have to make `Profile` type global also.

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You can use `$PropertyType`:

```
type Props = {
  profile: $PropertyType<State, 'profile'>
}
```

[Flow Utility Types - Property Type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-propertytype)

[Possible Bug with PropertyType](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3134)